# Connect to a port without use of netcat - alternatives

Tags: linux, networking, kali-linux, netcat

I want to connect to a port on a specific IP address without the use of netcat. I don't know of any method that would get the same result.

Below is me connecting to a port with netcat:

[image]

The above shows me connecting to port 22 (SSH) to a specific host. I basically want to achieve the same result but without the use of netcat.

Comment: Is this a homework question? Why wouldn't you use netcat? The question could be trivially answered by just telling you to rename the netcat executable ...

Comment: @cryptarch not homework. Just trying to advanced my arsenal of commands and different methods to achieving the same result.

Comment: Okay, in that case it might pay to check out the netcat source code and play around with some tcp/ip programming. Netcat is netcat, I'm not aware of anything which comes close to its combination of simplicity and utility for what it does.

Comment: What do you mean by "same result" - exactly the same output or just confirmation that you can connect? Would the `ssh` client help? Or `nmap -p22`? There is also the `telnet` client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious answer would be `telnet host.example.com port` (e. g. `telnet www.example.com 80`).

Another possibility is `/dev/tcp`:

```
$ echo "HEAD / HTTP/1.0" >/dev/tcp/www.example.com/80
```

Comment: `/dev/tcp` does not exist for Debian distros.

Comment: `/dev/tcp` is a shell internal from what I have seen, and is therefore distribution-independent.

Comment: I think you might be correct on that (saw something to that effect recently), BUT that doesn't mean that Debian left it in their shell. Regardless, there is no `dev/tcp` in any Debian distribution I've seen - certainly not in the ones I have access to. I don't like downvoting, but felt it was warranted here. If you'd like to revise, I'll remove it.

Comment: Debian does not use a Debian-specific fork of `bash` or `ksh` or other shells that implement `/dev/tcp`.  That "directory" is virtualized within the shell; it does not exist as a physical entity in `/dev`, so you will not see if if you try to find it with `ls /dev/tcp`.

Comment: Perhaps, but once again: It does not exist on any of my machines, and your answer does not work. I don't know what else to say.